# SSL breaks in app and never recovers (CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802))

Tags: ios

Occasionally my app will get into a state where all SSL/TLS network requests fail and it never recovers. This includes calls to our server, but also to Apple's servers (in app purchase lookup using a SKProductsRequest).

- Network requests in other apps on this device are working
- Another device on the same network could connect to those servers without issue
- Continues to happen if I switch from LTE to WiFi and back
- The only way to recover is to kill the app (but everything is fine after)
- The issue happens with every network request, regardless of target (tested our servers and Apple's servers)
- it's a production build from the app store
- repro'ed on iOS 9 (don't know if it occurs on other versions)

I connected to to the device and pulled logs, and every time the app tries to make a request I see this:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

Any idea what this is, and how I can fix it? Thanks for the help!